# How to prove that $\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sin^2(xy)}{yx^2}=\pi \delta(x)$

Tags: limits, fourier-transform

I want to understand how to prove that

$$\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sin^2(xy)}{yx^2}=\pi \delta(x)$$

The proof I am studying relies on doing the following Fourier Transform

$$\int dx \frac{\sin^2(xy)}{yx^2} \exp(-ipx) = \frac{\pi}{2} \Theta(2y - |p|) \Big(2-\frac{|p|}{y}\Big)$$

Which is shown by using the inverse of this formula. Then for $y \rightarrow \infty$ the right hand side goes to $\pi$ which gets you the limit proven.

However, I do not understand this proof. Could you please shed more details on it? If you have another kind of proof in mind please feel free to share it.

Thank you.

Comment: For $x\ne 0$, the function $\to 0$, as $y \to \infty$.  For $x\to 0$ the function $\to y$.  See what you can do with it.

Comment: @herbsteinberg I am afraid I do not see the method you're suggesting...

Comment: I am afraid I haven't gone any further, but see what that integral looks like with these approximations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we multiply the expression with a test function $\varphi.$ Then we integrate doing a variable substitution:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2(xy)}{yx^2} \varphi(x) \, dx
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \frac{\sin(xy)}{xy} \right)^2 \varphi(x) \, y \, dx
= \{ z = xy \}
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \frac{\sin(z)}{z} \right)^2 \varphi(\frac{z}{y}) \, dz \\
\to \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \frac{\sin(z)}{z} \right)^2 \varphi(0) \, dz
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \frac{\sin(z)}{z} \right)^2 \, dz \, \varphi(0)
.
$$

Here we can use the Plancherel theorem for the left integral:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \frac{\sin(z)}{z} \right)^2 \, dz
= \left< \frac{\sin(z)}{z}, \frac{\sin(z)}{z} \right>
= \frac{1}{2\pi} \left< \mathcal{F}\{\frac{\sin(z)}{z}\}, \mathcal{F}\{\frac{\sin(z)}{z}\} \right> \\
= \frac{1}{2\pi} \left< \pi\chi_{[-1,1]}, \pi\chi_{[-1,1]} \right>
= \frac{\pi^2}{2\pi} \int_{-1}^{1} dx 
= \pi
.
$$

---

**Why is $\mathcal{F}\{\frac{\sin(z)}{z}\} = \pi\chi_{[-1,1]}$?**

We have
$$
\mathcal{F}\{\chi_{[-1,1]}(z)\}(\zeta)
= \int \chi_{[-1,1]}(z) \, e^{-i\zeta z} dz
= \left[ \frac{e^{-i\zeta z}}{-i\zeta} \right]_{-1}^{1}
= \frac{e^{-i\zeta}}{-i\zeta} - \frac{e^{i\zeta}}{-i\zeta}
= 2\frac{\sin(\zeta)}{\zeta}
,
$$
so by the [Fourier inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem),
$$
\mathcal{F}\{2\frac{\sin(z)}{z}\}(\zeta)
= 2\pi \chi_{[-1,1]}(\zeta),
$$
i.e.
$$
\mathcal{F}\{\frac{\sin(z)}{z}\}(\zeta)
= \pi \chi_{[-1,1]}(\zeta),
$$

Comment: I do not see how you got $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ out of $\mathcal{F}\{\frac{\sin(z)}{z}\}$.Could you shed more light on it? I think you're computing the following FT $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-1}^{1} \Big(\frac{\sin z}{z} \Big) e^{izx} dz$ but, using an online source to compute integrals,I got the following result (please see next comment). Is this equivalent to $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$? If not I do not see what I am missing...

Comment: $-\dfrac{\mathrm{i}\left(\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(0,\mathrm{i}x+\mathrm{i}\right)-\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(0,\mathrm{i}x-\mathrm{i}\right)+\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(0,\mathrm{i}-\mathrm{i}x\right)-\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(0,-\mathrm{i}x-\mathrm{i}\right)\right)}{2^\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{{\pi}}}$

Comment: @JD_PM. I've added an explanation. I also made a change in the existing calculation, since I chose another definition of the Fourier transform.

Comment: Now it is more clear, thanks. Could you add more details on why $\mathcal{F}\{2\frac{\sin(z)}{z}\}(\zeta)
= 2\pi \chi_{[-1,1]}(\zeta)$? (I may be asking too much, you've been really helpful so far!).

Comment: @JD_PM. The Fourier inversion theorem says that if $\mathcal{F}\{f(z)\} = g(\zeta),$ then $\mathcal{F}\{g(z)\} = 2\pi f(-\zeta).$ I just use this with $f(z) = \chi_{[-1,1]}(z)$ and $g(z)=2 \frac{\sin(z)}{z}.$ I think that it will be too technical to go into more details.

Answer (score 1):

If $f\in L^1(\Bbb{R})$ with $ c=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}n f(n.)=c\delta$ in the sense of distributions.

Proof : with $\phi \in C^0_c(\Bbb{R})$ then
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty n f(nx)\phi(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty  f(x)\phi(x/n)dx=\int_{-A}^A  f(x)(\phi(0)+o(1))dx+O(\int_{|x|>A} |f(x)|dx)$$

Answer (score 1):

This can be seen in terms of approximations to the identity. The kernel
$\mathcal{K}_R(y)=\frac{\sin^2(R\pi y)}{R(\pi y)^2}$, called the Fejér kernel, is integrable. In fact, $\mathcal{K}_R(y)=R\mathcal{K}_1(Ry)$, and $\int \mathcal{K}_1(y)\,dy=1$. This can be seen by noticing that $\mathcal{K}_1(y)$ is the Fourier transform of the tent distribution $\phi(t)=(1-|t|)_+$, which is the convolution of the uniform distribution in $(-1/2,1/2)$ with itself.

Then, for any $f\in\mathcal{L}_p$, $\|\mathcal{K}_R*f-f\|_p\xrightarrow{R\rightarrow\infty}0$, and convergene pointwise also holds at every Lebesgue point of $f$. If you use test functions $f\in\mathcal{S}$ (Schwartz functions), then $\mathcal{K}_R*f\rightarrow f$ point wise, that is $K_R$ behaves like a delta function. A brief explanation of approximations to the identity is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3681080/how-to-find-lim-limits-t-to-infty-int-limits-0-infty-ux-t-dx/3681140#3681140).